# Select row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function in Google Sheets that is giving the following output:

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

I don't want the `a b c` I just want the `1 2 3`. What function can I wrap around my other function so that it will only show me `1 2 3`. I tried `array_constrain` I want something in the spirit of `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A1:C2,2:2,3)`, but that formula doesn't work.

I just want the 2nd row. The "other function" is a `query` with aggregates at the top like "avg" and "sum". I don't want to see that. I don't want to hide it because I have to paste down.

Comment: So, each value is in a separate row/column?

Comment: correct, it is 2 rows x 3 columns

Comment: I curious as to which function gives that result. Can you give us a hint?

Comment: I've tried to get rid of the aggregates at the top using the third parameter in the `query` function, doesn't seem like you can do it.

Comment: The only alternative I can think of is to change each column to a `filter` function and paste down with averages and sums. It's a really clumsy work around especially if you have alot of columns

Comment: Are the letters the headers?

Comment: Yes, the letters are the "sum" and "avg" that the query function spits out. I don't want to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need to do.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(A1:C2, "SELECT * OFFSET 1", 0)
```

### Explained

The `SELECT` statement contains an extra `OFFSET` argument. It tells the query to skip one row. The third parameter of the `QUERY` formula controls the headers. Setting it to zero will ignore the headers.

Comment: wow, clever answer! double query.